# WPF PropertyMetadata does not work properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a `ToggleSwitch` `UserControl`. `ToggleSwitch` has `DependencyProperty` called `IsChecked` and this shows check status of `UserControl`

`ToggleSwitch.xaml.cs` :

```
public bool IsChecked {
    get { return ( bool ) GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(ToggleSwitch), 
        new PropertyMetadata(false, IsCheckedPropertyOnChanged));


private static void IsCheckedPropertyOnChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    if ( obj is ToggleSwitch ) {
        var res = ( ( ToggleSwitch ) obj );
        res.ChangeStatus();
    }
}
```

At the same time `IsChecked` status can change when 'GridMouseLeftButtonDown' event occurs (So the user click the `ToggleSwitch`):

```
private void GridOnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    IsChecked = !IsChecked;
}
```

The appearance changes with the `ChangeStatus` function.

Below code shows how I bind the `IsChecked` in MainWindow.xaml

```
<local:ToggleSwitch IsChecked="{Binding SelectedPerson.IsActive}"/>
```

`SelectedPerson`is a `DependencyProperty` in MainWindow.xaml.cs.

The `IsChecked` property changes successfully every time I create a new instance of `SelectedPerson`.

But once `GridOnMouseLeftButtonDown` (`ToggleSwitch` ClickEvent) fires, the `IsCheckedPropertyOnChanged` no longer invokes.

Small project example to show the problem:

### `ToggleSwitch.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class ToggleSwitch : UserControl {


    public bool IsChecked {
        get { return ( bool ) GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(ToggleSwitch),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, IsCheckedPropertyOnChanged));
    private static void IsCheckedPropertyOnChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        if ( obj is ToggleSwitch ) {
            var res = ( ( ToggleSwitch ) obj );
            res.ChangeStatus();
        }
    }

    public ToggleSwitch() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ChangeStatus() {
        if ( IsChecked ) {
            MainContainer.Background = Brushes.Green;
        } else {
            MainContainer.Background = Brushes.Red;
        }
    }

    private void GridOnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        IsChecked = !IsChecked;
    }
}
```

### `ToggleSwitch.xaml`:

```
<Grid MouseLeftButtonDown="GridOnMouseLeftButtonDown" Width="150" Height="150">
    <Border x:Name="MainContainer" Width="150" Height="150" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White"/>
</Grid>
```

### `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public class Person {
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public Person SelectedPerson {
        get { return ( Person ) GetValue(SelectedPersonProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedPersonProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedPerson.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedPersonProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedPerson", typeof(Person), typeof(MainWindow));



    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        SelectedPerson = new Person {
            IsActive = true
        };
    }

    private void ButtonOnClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var change = !SelectedPerson.IsActive;
        SelectedPerson = new Person {
            IsActive = change
        };
    }
}
```

### `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <local:ToggleSwitch IsChecked="{Binding SelectedPerson.IsActive}" />
    <Button Content="ChangeItemSource" Click="ButtonOnClicked" Width="150" Margin="50" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example to reproduce ?

Comment: Be aware that assigning a value to a dependency property replaces a previously assigned OneWay Binding. You may use a TwoWay Binding instead.

Comment: @Cfun question updated with sample project to show error

Comment: @Clemens Your suggestion solved the problem